# How do you stop sendmail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendmail

At least.. I think its sendmail.

Bascially I have a rails application running through SendGrid.

Long story short, a job was queued and errored, and delayed_jobs was running even though it wasn't displaying any data on it. Then we queued another one after deleting that job. Then the emails started coming out. So we thought it was working.

Wrong. It kept sending them.

I stopped delayed_jobs. Destroyed all its objects. Killed any/all of its process with kill -9 seeing htat /stop didn't work.

The delayed_job log said it wasn't sending emails. But when I checked the `/var/log/mail.log`, that is **still** sending emails.

How do I stop this?

I tried /sbin/sendmail stop , but it just freezes. I checked /sbin/sendmail -bp and it says mail queue is empty. So maybe its not sendmail?

Basically I'm snapshotting my database, and preparing to kill the entire application.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked *both* sendmail queues? [sendmail-8.12+]

```
/sbin/sendmail -Ac -bp
/sbin/sendmail -Am -bp
```

It is possible that messages has been stored in "client queue" for delivery to/via `127.0.0.1:25`